# How to check if the internal typedef struct of a typedef struct is NULL?

Tags: c, struct, pointers, typedef

```
typedef struct
{   
   uint32 item1;
   uint32 item2;
   uint32 item3;
   uint32 item4;

   <some_other_typedef struct> *table;

} Inner_t;

typedef struct
{
   Inner_t tableA;

   Inner_t tableB;

} Outer_t;

Outer_t outer_instance =
{
   {NULL},
   {
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,

    table_defined_somewhere_else,
   }
};
```

My question is how to check if tableA is NULL just like the case for outer_instance.

It tried:
 `if ( tmp->tableA == NULL )`. I get "error: invalid operands to binary =="

/****************************EDIT:Updated code is below *****************************/

I've changed the code according to bta's suggestion but now I'm getting another error
"error: initializer element is not constant" at the line just under the NULL(at items_instance)

```
typedef struct
{   
   uint32 item1;
   uint32 item2;
   uint32 item3;
   uint32 item4;

} Items_t;

typedef struct
{
   Items_t *itemsA;

   Items_t *itemsB;

} Outer_t;


Items_t items_instance=
{   
   1,
   2,
   3,
   4
};

Outer_t outer_instance=
{
   NULL,
   items_instance

};
```

Comment: Makes no sense. `tableA` cannot be `NULL`. Field `tableA` has `Inner_t` type. `Inner_t` is a struct, not a pointer. Comparing a struct object to `NULL` makes no sense whatsoever, which is what the compiler is telling you. Explain what is it you are trying to do.

Comment: I understand your point AndreyT.I know that the compiler is telling me  I can't compare a struct object to NULL coz its not a pointer.
See,I need to check if tableA in an Outer_t struct is empty/NULL or hasn't been defined or doesn't exist (whatever the correct term is) then use tableB.That's all.
There's a second alternative.which is to make "Inner_t *tableA;" inside Outer_t.but then how could I instantiate outer_instance with tableA empty/NULL ...

Comment: if tableA was `Inner_t *tableA` instead, you would initialize it to NULL exactly like your code is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the revised code, you're setting the first field of `outer_instance` to NULL, but trying to set the second field to `items_instance` directly. Since the field has type `Items_t*` but `items_instance` has type `Items_t`, you're getting a type error.

You want to set the field to the **address** of `items_instance`, so use `&items_instance`.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, the initialization

```
Outer_t outer_instance = {
   {NULL},
   {
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    table_defined_somewhere_else,
   }
};
```

is invalid.  You are trying to assign `NULL` to `Outer_t.tableA` which is of non-pointer type `Inner_t`.  `NULL` can only be assigned to pointers.

Most C compilers define `NULL` as `0` or `((void*)0)`.  Depending on your compiler, this syntax *may* be allowed but will be expanded to `0`, effectively setting all fields in the first `Inner_t` structure to zero.  In any case, this code will not do what I think you believe it will.

Your notion of `tableA` being undefined or non-existent is wrong.  As your structures are currently defined, declaring an object of type `Outer_t` will automatically create two `Inner_t` objects as structure members (and those `Inner_t` structures will automatically create the objects they are composed of, etc).  If `outer_instance` exists, then `outer_instance.tableA` and `outer_instance.tableB` are guaranteed to exist.  They cannot be "undefined" (they are defined when you defined the `Outer_t` data type) or "NULL" (has no meaning except for pointers).  A structure which has members defined is never "empty".

Now, it is a valid concern whether or not `tableA` or `tableB` have been initialized.  There is no universally-appropriate way to do this.  One method is to fill the entire structure with some pre-defined value when it is declared, and to check for the presence of that value as a sign that the structure has not been initialized.  This assumes, however, that there is a value that you should never see as valid data within that structure; many times, such a value does not exist.

If you want to build your code in such a way that the members of `Outer_t` may or may not exist, then you should use pointers (such as `Inner_t* tableA`) as members of `Outer_t` instead of structures.  That way, you can NULL the pointer to indicate a non-existent table.  However, you would not be able to declare the contents of the inner structs at the same time as the outer struct in the manner which you currently do.

**Edit:**
Looking at your updated code, it appears that you are getting that particular error because you are trying to assign an object of type `Items_t` to a field of type `Items_t*`.  Use `&items_instance` here and your error should go away (provided that `items_instance` is defined *before* `outer_instance`, and all elements of `items_instance` can be determined at compile time).

Answer (score 0):

Try  `if ( tmp->tableA.`**`table`**`== NULL )`